# Having issues getting transform-origin working

Tags: css, css-transforms

I am new to using transform-origin and I have been having difficulties getting it to work.
I am currently making a simple image carousel and for one image the aspect ratio is different than the other images making the origin/center point of the image not where I want it to display, as it only shows the top left of the image. I looked up a solution for this and I was told transform-origin would solve it. However I have been entering different values inside the 2nd image and the transform-origin property still isn't changing the center point of the image.

I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

The CSS code in question starts at the slider section.

```css
/***********************/
/* CSS Reset */
/***********************/
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: "";
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/***********************/
/* Color Palette */
/***********************/
/* Black */ /* #010101 */

/* #800020 */
/* #66001A */
/* #520015 */
/* #420011 */

/* #4f2f2f */
/* #2f4f4f */
/* #426F6F */
/* #568E8E */
/* #94bebe */
/* #d1e4e4 */

/* #8e7256 */

/* #8e5656 */

/***********************/
/* Spacing System */
/***********************/
/* 2 / 4 / 8 / 12 / 16 / 24 / 32 / 48 / 64 / 80 / 96 / 128*/

/***********************/
/* Header */
/***********************/
header {
  background-color: #010101;
  height: 6.4rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1.6rem;
}
.logo-title {
  font-family: "Charmonman Bold";
  color: #8e5656;
  font-size: 3rem;

  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 1.2rem;
}

/***********************/
/* Navigation */
/***********************/
nav {
  color: #8e5656;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-family: "Crimson Text Regular";
}
.main-nav-list {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  gap: 3.6rem;
  margin-right: 4.8rem;
}
.main-nav-list a:link,
.main-nav-list a:visited {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #8e5656;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.main-nav-list a:hover,
.main-nav-list a:active {
  color: #af8e8e;
}

/***********************/
/* Slider */
/***********************/
.slide {
  height: 80rem;
}
.slide img {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90rem;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.img-2 {
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Charmonman Regular";
  src: url("/fonts/Charmonman-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Charmonman Bold";
  src: url("/fonts/Charmonman-Bold.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Amarelle Regular";
  src: url("/fonts/AmarelleDemoRegular.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Crimson Text Regular";
  src: url("/fonts/CrimsonText-regular.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Saphrel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header">
      <h1 class="logo-title">Saphrel</h1>
      <nav class="main-nav">
        <ul class="main-nav-list">
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Our Story</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Reservations</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <section aria-label="Newest Photos">
      <div class="slider">
        <ul>
          <li class="slide">
            <img
              src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/18/14/05/brick-wall-1834784_960_720.jpg"
              alt="Picture of Restaurant"
            />
          </li>
          <li class="slide">
            <img
              class="img-2"
              src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/370984/pexels-photo-370984.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
              alt="Picture of Wine Glass and Dish"
            />
          </li>
          <li class="slide">
            <img
              src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/6267/menu-restaurant-vintage-table.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
              alt="Picture of Wine Glass"
            />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
    <h1>test</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can’t see any transforming going on in the code you have given. Please make a snippet that shows the problem.

Comment: Turns out I was looking at the wrong css property. object-position seems to be the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was looking at the wrong css property. object-position seems to be the one I was looking for.